# What is the easiest way of adding images in Shiny app?

Tags: r, image, shiny

I am trying to find the simplest way of adding images in shiny.

To me, the simplest way I found consists in the following two steps:

- STEP 1: Create "www" folder in the same directory where the ui.R code is.
- STEP 2: Add your image into the "www" folder.
- STEP 3: Add the following in the ui.R file:

```
img(src="my_image.png", height="100%", width="100%", align = "center")
```

Practical example embedding an image in a side bar section in my ui.R:

```
shinyUI(
  navbarPage("Ocean Best Practices System Dashboard",
             
             tabPanel("Intro",
                      sidebarPanel(
                        img(src="obps_logo.png", height="100%", width="100%", align = "center")
                      ),
                      mainPanel(
                        h1("Ocean Best Practices System - Dashboard", align = "left"),
                        p("Ocean Best Practices System esta integrado dentro de ....."),                        
                      )
             ),
```

The result looks as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VO75M.png)

Comment: You have identified the simplest way.